# Decrypt in Python an encrypted message in Java

Tags: java, python, aes, m2crypto

I'm trying to decrypt in Python (with M2Crypto) an encrypted message generated in Java with this [library](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings)

My code (which I actually found here) works decrypting messages encrypted by itself, but not from Java's library, I get the following error:

```
EVPError: 'wrong final block length'
```

I have tried both *aes_128_cbc* and *aes_128_ecb* and I get the same error.

I guess the failure is that Java's result is Ascii's encoded and Python's code is expecting some other encoding (as it works with base64) but I don't know where to make the change (in my Python's code). I'm open to use any other Python encryption library.

Thanks

```
import M2Crypto
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

ENC=1
DEC=0

def AES_build_cipher(key, iv, op=ENC):
    """"""""
    return M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher(alg='aes_128_cbc', key=key, iv=iv, op=op)

def AES_encryptor(key,msg, iv=None):
    """"""
    #Decode the key and iv
    key = b64decode(key)
    if iv is None:
        iv = '\0' * 16
    else:
        iv = b64decode(iv)

   # Return the encryption function
    def encrypt(data):
        cipher = AES_build_cipher(key, iv, ENC)
        v = cipher.update(data)
        v = v + cipher.final()
        del cipher
        v = b64encode(v)
        return v
    print "AES encryption successful\n"
    return encrypt(msg)

def AES_decryptor(key,msg, iv=None):
    """"""
    #Decode the key and iv
    key = b64decode(key)
    print key
    print
    if iv is None:
        iv = '\0' * 16
    else:
        iv = b64decode(iv)

   # Return the decryption function
    def decrypt(data):
        data = b64decode(data)
        cipher = AES_build_cipher(key, iv, DEC)
        v = cipher.update(data)
        v = v + cipher.final()
        del cipher
        return v
    print "AES dencryption successful\n"
    return decrypt(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = AES_decryptor(b64encode(SECRET_KEY), msg=encrypted_message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "ascii encoded" mean? As you know, my code expected base64 input and produced base64 output. Removing the calls to `b64decode` and `b64encode` in the `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions will let you pass in raw data, then it'll be up to you to decode the input from Java into raw bytes.

Comment: You are right, I have deleted every b64encode/decode call, but I have made some other changes to match Java JCE encryption results in ECB mode (not in CBC as the code uses).

I also have replaced *key* value for *key.decode("hex")* in both methods and *v = b64encode(v)* for *v = v.encode("hex")* in the encryption method.